# System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'System.IO.StreamWriter'

Tags: c#, ssis, .net-3.0

I tried to convert an Object variable into a StreamWriter. But, it does not work. What is the mistake ?

```
StreamWriter file = (StreamWriter) myObject;
```

Comment: Well it's a `System.Object` - it's not a `System.IO.StreamWriter`. Where did you get it from, and why did you *expect* to be able to cast it to `StreamWriter`?

Comment: myObject is actually an SSIS variable which was obtained using the code `Object myObject = Dts.Variables["yourStreamWriterHere"].Value;`

Again, don't worry about that here.  Lets look at the c# instead.

Comment: @JonSkeet - My answer is given below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another moment of my stupidity. I had commented out the line that does this - `Object myObject = Dts.Variables["yourStreamWriterHere"].Value;` So, there was nothing inside `myObject`. Is there a null there ? In Java it is. Also, java gives you a nice `nullPointerException`. But, visual studio gives you a cryptic "**Micro$lop™**: Cannot find the cause of error. Contact **Billy** for more help. Keep your credit card handy just in case. Call center waiting times vary". Just irritating.

Anyway, the real error you get is -

```
Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'System.IO.StreamWriter'.
   at ST_ffrrefr939322939392dfr.csproj.ScriptMain.Main()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
```

Comment: Yes, this would be a null if you didn't assign it. You don't get a NullReferenceException because there is no derefencing going on.

Comment: @blasto : yes then it surly contains null, and when you are invoking any function on it throws null refrence Exception

Comment: @blast - In C#, objects that are `null` actually do have a type; You can cast `null` to any type that you want. For example, you can pass null as a parameter of a method, so long as the null that you pass is of the same type as said parameter of the method.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel - why is that allowed ?

Comment: @blasto dereferencing is what happens when you try to do something with the value of a reference. In your example, myObject is a reference to an object. If you were to call `myObject.ToString()`, for example, you would dereference the reference and because it was referencing null, you would get the NullReferenceException.

Comment: @blasto - Imagine that you have a method that initializes a given `out` parameter by attempting to parse some string and doing some other logic. The method's call could then take a form like the following: `SomeClass sc = null; InitializeSC("someString", out sc);`. Subsequently, the code could check to see if `sc` was initialized or if it is still `null`, and do something to handle the result of that check, etc. Some actual examples of this pattern are the `TryParse` methods for `Int32` and `DateTime`.

Answer (score 3):

The value of `myObject` is not (convertable to) a StreamWriter.

Comment: I noticed the word value carefully now. Makes sense. My value was a null.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if (myObject is StreamWriter) 
{
    var file = (StreamWriter) myObject as StreamWriter;
}
```

Comment: This works regardless of whether or not `myObject` is `null`. However, in C# there is a difference between an object that is `null` and an object that is uninitialized. As such, the above works if `myObject` has been declared and initialized via `object myObject = null` but not if it has just been declared via `object myObject;` without initialization. In your case, I assume that `myObject` is a parameter (of type `object`) to a method and that a `StreamWriter` was passed. So long as that `StreamWriter` has been initialized, even as `StreamWriter sw = null;`, the above will work without error.

Answer (score 1):

Before converting, check if it can be cast to a `StreamWriter` object by using the `is` keyword, as below:

```
if(myObject is StreamWriter)
{
//can be cast
}
else
{
//can not be cast
}
```